Why do I Get an Attribute Error While Running The Code of Google Translator(with gui)?
Here, I'm trying to make a google translator(translate languages) in python idle (version: 3.12) using GUI but have got some errors. I've tried to solve it multiple times but it later gives another error. As I'm new to python, I can't really figure out what's the major error and how to solve it, so I'm here! Asking you guys out, hoping to seek help.
The code I made is the following:
# Google Transalator

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk # Imports a combobox

from googletrans import Translator,LANGUAGES

#translate the language
def change(text = "type",src = "English",dest = "Urdu" ):
    text1 = text
    src1 = src
    dest1 = dest
    trans = Translator()
    trans1 = trans.translate(text,src = src1,dest = dest1) 
    return tarns1.text

# get the data
def data():
    s = comb_sor.get()
    d = comb_dest.get()
    msg = sor_txt.get(1.0,END)
    textget = change(text = msg, src = s, dest = d)
    dest_txt.delete(1.0,END)
    dest_txt.insert(END,textget)

root = Tk()
root.title("Translator")
root.geometry("500x600")
root.config(bg = "LightBlue")


lab_txt = Label(root, text = "Translator", font = ("Roboto",40,"bold"),bg = "white", fg =           "black")
lab_txt.place(x = 100,y = 20,height = 70, width = 300)

# build a frame

frame = Frame(root).pack(side = BOTTOM)

lab_txt = Label(root, text = "Text", font = ("Roboto",20,"bold"),bg = "LightBlue",fg = "black")
lab_txt.place(x = 100,y = 107,height = 30, width = 300)

# build source text box

sor_txt = Text(frame,font = ("Roboto",22,"bold"),bg = "SkyBlue", fg = "black",  wrap = WORD)
sor_txt.place(x = 10 ,y = 150 ,height = 130,width = 480)


# build comb text box

list_txt = list(LANGUAGES.values())

comb_sor =  ttk.Combobox(frame, value = list_txt)
comb_sor.place(x = 10 ,y = 300 ,height = 44,width = 100)
comb_sor.set("english")


# creat a button

button_change = Button(frame, text = "Transalte",font = ("Roboto",40,"bold"), relief = RAISED, command = data)# relief and raised will let the button work  
button_change.place(x = 125 ,y = 300 ,height = 70,width = 250)

# create combobox 2

comb_dest =  ttk.Combobox(frame, value = list_txt)
comb_dest.place(x = 390 ,y = 300 ,height = 44,width = 100)
comb_dest.set("english")

# make a text for translation

dest_txt = Label(root, text = "Translation", font = ("Roboto",20,"bold"),bg = "LightBlue",fg =   "black")
dest_txt.place(x = 100,y = 385,height = 30, width = 300)

root.mainloop()

Please ignore my comments on the code, I wrote them for my own understanding.
When I run the code I gave, I get the following error:
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 
1968, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Hania\Desktop\ppp\Google Translator.py", line 23, 
in 
data
    textget = change(text = msg, src = s, dest = d)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Hania\Desktop\ppp\Google Translator.py", line 15, 
in 
change
    trans1 = trans.translate(text,src = src1,dest = dest1)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site- 
   packages\googletrans\client.py", line 182, in translate
        data = self._translate(text, dest, src, kwargs)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site- 
   packages\googletrans\client.py", line 78, in _translate
        token = self.token_acquirer.do(text)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site- 
   packages\googletrans\gtoken.py", line 194, in do
        self._update()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site- 
       packages\googletrans\gtoken.py", line 62, in _update
        code = self.RE_TKK.search(r.text).group(1).replace('var ', '')
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

I would like any of you to help me out figure what is the problem and solve it! :)
